# WMS Requests - does 1 request = 1 response tile

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms

I'm using OpenLayers and GeoServer when I pan or zoom the map - OpenLayers kicks of a series of WMS requests. Does 1 WMS request = 1 tile in response?

I'd have thought if you sent a WMS request with the map extents then we'd get multiple responses back to reduce the number of requests - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 1 request is 1 tile. Getting several tiles in a single response is not possible, but if your GeoServer is serving "raw" wms'es (i.e. not cached tiles), you can tell OpenLayers not to request tiles, see the [singleTile option](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.singleTile).

Comment: Thanks.The single tile is not an option as this is an Ortho layer and the single tile size would be masssive and unusable.

Comment: well, re-consider that: it's not the whole layer as a tile returned once, but instead of requesting several 256x256 px tiles it's one "tile" that fits the map viewport.

But again: i do not think there is a real problem in requesting a bunch of tiles

Comment: Alright I didnt realize that. So basically if my OpenLayers map is in a container that is 600x400 GeoServer will serve up a single tile of that size - i'm guessing this requires GeoServer to work to create an image of that size and that caching wont be possible.

Comment: Correct, and this is why tiles with a given size is used